# Is there a way to pass data between activities in an activity group?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, activitygroup

I have all of my intents in activity groups so I can navigate easily using tabs. I've now encountered the problem where I need to pass information to another activity and I don't know how to approach because the activity isn't loaded the normal way.

Here is how I call the new activity:

```
setContentView(view);
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I put up a custom method because I'm stupid. Fixed now.

Comment: What is replaceView? I've never heard of such a function, and I can't find reference to such a function in the documentation. Is it a custom function you've created? If so, please post the code for it.

Comment: Sorry, I accidently posted the wrong segment. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ok, in this case, Manfred Moser's answer definitely applies. The `setContentView` doesn't create a new activity, it only populates the UI for the activity that you're currently in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are saying but if you are just replacing the view you are not going to a new activity so everything should still be in scope and accessible.

Comment: There's  class caled an activity group, and it holds a group of activities. Instead of having one activity tied to a tab, you can replace it with the group. This way, when the new activity is started, you don't lose the tab navigation.

What I am looking for, is a way to pass data between activities int he group.